# Import module and call method in dynamic Angular component

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I have created a Angular 7 dynamic component that uses Angular material MatDialog to call another component. This is giving me  Unexpected value 'MatDialog' imported by the module 'class_2'. Please add a @NgModule annotation. But if I don't add MatDialog, I get: Can't resolve all parameters for class_1: (?).

Please help. Thank you.

Dynamic component creation:

```
@ViewChild('vc', {read: ViewContainerRef}) vc: ViewContainerRef;

constructor(private _compiler: Compiler,
            private _injector: Injector,
            private _m: NgModuleRef<any>) {
}

ngAfterViewInit() {
  const template = '<span (click)="openDialog()">Click Here</span>';

  const tmpCmp = Component({template: template})(class {
    constructor(private _dialog: MatDialog) {}

    openDialog() {
      this._dialog.open(AnotherComponent, {});
    }
  });

  const tmpModule = NgModule({
    imports: [CommonModule, MatDialog],
    declarations: [tmpCmp],
  })(class {
  });

  this._compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync(tmpModule)
    .then((factories) => {
      const f = factories.componentFactories[0];
      const cmpRef = this.vc.createComponent(f);
      cmpRef.instance.name = 'dynamic';
    })
}
```

Comment: Are you able to fix this? facing same error

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you import `MatDialogModule` in `NgModule` `imports` array?